# Logged in user name disappeares when navigating to another page

Tags: asp.net

In my first asp.net application, there are a master page & few WebForm pages. In the master page, there is a asp.net label control to show current user name. After login from Default.aspx , a user lands on Dashboard.aspx page. Master page label shows current user name correctly. But when i navigate to other page, current user name is disappearing. I am setting current user name in Dashboard.aspx page as the following -

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["CurrentUser"] ==null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
         UserLogin user=(UserLogin) Session["CurrentUser"];

         Label userName = (Label)Master.FindControl("lblLoginName");
         if (userName != null)
         {
             userName.Text ="Welcome, " + user.EmployeeName;
         }

     }
}
```

How to overcome this issue? 
Thank you.

Comment: Not very sure if this will solve the issue but did you try enabling view state for label? EnableViewState = "true" for the label?

Comment: Then did you tried disabling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the label is in Master page you do not have to set it in page, simply set it on page load of Master page and effects will take place on every page.